# Is there a method for generating multiple irregular polygons and/or irregular blobs of equal surface area using p5.js?

Tags: polygon, p5.js, area

For neuroscience research I'm attempting to train rats to press shapes on a touch screen. Ideally, these shapes would be highly distinct polygons or blobs to make it easier for the rats to discriminate. However, to limit some biases toward certain shapes, I'd like to keep the area of each shape equivalent. I've been trying to achieve this on p5.js, but I'm very new to this.

The code I've got so far provides some of the shape randomness, but not the consitency in area:

```
function setup() {

createCanvas(500, 500);  
background(255);
fill(0);

translate(width/2, height/2);
beginShape();

for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
const x = random(-250, 250);
const y = random(-250, 250);
vertex(x, y);
endShape();
}   
}
```

Any help achieving this would be very appreciated

Comment: You mean same area or same “bounding box” area? The second is easy.

Comment: I was hoping for the same surface area not just the same bounding box. Although, now you mention it, I'm also interested in maintaining the same bounding box area. @v.k.

Comment: I’ll get you some code when I get to my computer :) polygons inside a circle.

Comment: Are you familiar with java's processing? The 'origin' of p5js?

Comment: Never mind I converted the code

Comment: That would be a huge help, thanks a lot :)
I'm wasn't familiar with the origin of p5js, but I just read a brief history about it and its relationship with Processing here: https://cathyatseneca.gitbooks.io/introduction-to-p5-js/content/chapter1.html

Comment: Its very similar code... not a big deal

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's not what you need, the shapes are all inscribed in a circle(**edit**:the second code ones), not a bounding box as I said earlier.

Both examples are online at p5js editor:

The code I had was more free form, it will eternally increase the number of sides:

about 20 sides:
[image: screenshot]

about 130 sides
[image: screenshot]

But at the begining its more what I think you need

the code is here:

https://editor.p5js.org/v-k-/sketches/siYtDw423

And...
I made a tweeked version to try to go closer to what I think you want :)

[image: screenshot]

The code is here:

https://editor.p5js.org/v-k-/sketches/oMsWC2NHv

Perhaps you can play with the numbers to get What you need. For instance:

You can set the number of sides, or even reject sides smaller than something.

It's very simple stuff ;) Easy to tweek.
Have fun, hope the rats like it.

Comment: Great, looks very cool, thanks! I'll spend I bit of time playing around with this and let you know if it meets my (and the rats) needs.

Comment: Great, have fun :)